# Fetching “id” from first 5 tags and separate them with comma in output using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on one of script where I need to pull the value available in id on tag  I need to use pure Javascript to get this done. I have similar jQuery code available but I am not able to successfully complete Javascript one.
My jquery Code

```
var arr1st3 = $('article:lt(3)').map(function() {
    return this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}).get();
console.log( arr1st3 );
```

Here is the test url 
http://jsfiddle.net/0mvjbkhs/5/

I am trying to have Javascript function that will return the values in output like ***['123456', '7896669', '1147777']***

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure javascript version would be:

```
var arr2st3 = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('article:nth-child(-n+4)'), function(el) {
    return el.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
});
```

Quite similar. You just use native [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and `article:nth-child(-n+4)` CSS selector to select elements.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/0mvjbkhs/6/

Comment: If you're going pure JS, you should total make an ES6 version

Comment: this is working on domready, however @dfsq can you please advise if this will behave equally well on all browsers? or as Sterling mentioned it will have any limitation ?

Comment: Here is DOMContentLoaded version (pure analog of jQuery ready event) http://jsfiddle.net/0mvjbkhs/7/. For IE < 9 you should use `window.onload = function () { ... }` instead. Maping code will work everywhere without any limitations. What Sterling mentioned about ES6 is just another syntax (supported by only modern browsers).

Comment: @dfsq you are more than awesome really appreciate you help, one last request if you can help. What if I need to use your script as a function, I tried to created but not able to get output -> https://jsfiddle.net/v3d0nz9d/